# Core Animation is not working with "alpha" value

Tags: ios, core-animation, alpha, cabasicanimation

Before this code, my movie pic alpha is set to 0,

```
CABasicAnimation* fadein= [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"alpha"];
    [fadein setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]];
    [fadein setDuration:0.5];
    [[moviepic layer]addAnimation:fadein forKey:@"alpha"];
```

Nothing happened, if I set alpha to 0.5 beforehand instead, the alpha remains at 0.5 and not animating to 1.

I've seen a code using `UIView beginAnimations:` around, but I'm teaching core animation so I wondered why CABasicAnimation can't do simple task like this?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

```
[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
```

UIView exposes this as `alpha` where as CALayer exposes this as `opacity`.

Comment: What O_o I'll try this soon. But is there anymore case like this? And where can I check that what can I use for KeyPath? (normally I'd check on object's property which has setAlpha in it but in this case it doesn't match...)

Comment: @Sargon With Core Animation you are animating `CALayer` properties, not `UIView` properties, so the layer is the place to look for correct property names - see: `view.layer`.

Answer (score 2):

For Swift:

```
let opacity = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
opacity.fromValue = fromValue
opacity.toValue = toValue
opacity.duration = duration
opacity.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + beginTime  //If a delay is needed

view.layer.add(opacity, forKey: nil)
```

If you want to keep the final `alpha` value, you have to set the current view controller as the delegate of the opacity animation:

```
opacity.delegate = self
```

And, in the delegate function `animationDidStop`, you should do:

```
extension ViewController: CAAnimationDelegate {

    func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {   
        view.alpha = toValue
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@ohho answers the posted question. Mine will be a bit more generic. For a list what can and how be animated with `CABasicAnimation` please refer to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/AnimatableProperties/AnimatableProperties.html)